# error con docker instalado en una maquina de arquitectura de 32bits

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Hola a todos quisiera saber a que se debe este error

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container ffb: [8] System error: exec format error
FATA[0000] Error: failed to start one or more containers
```

este error se genera al querer iniciar un contenedor con el comando

```
sudo docker start [idContainer]
```

como les digo estoy en una maquina de 32 bits, no se si esto sea de utilidad al digitar el comando de info este es el kernel que muestra
Kernel Version: 3.19.0-59-generic

les agradeceria que me pudieran ayudar a resolver este error, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser que demonio docker no este inicializado; apt-get install -f && service docker start

Comment: ese comando arroja este resultado:
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25 linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-85-generic linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 16 no actualizados.
start: Job is already running: docker

Answer (score 2):

Estos son los prerquisitos :  Necesitas 64 bits

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

**Prerequisites**
Docker requires a 64-bit installation regardless of your Ubuntu version. Additionally, your kernel must be 3.10 at minimum. The latest 3.10 minor version or a newer maintained version are also acceptable.

Comment: Hola @andrxs efectivamente solo es para verisones de 64 bits, no hubo forma de poder instalarlo en una desktop de 32, saludos

Comment: Ya me imaginaba, si yo también tuve esos problemas. Necesitas un S.O de 64bits.